# What are the steps to verify LTL with SPIN tool?

Tags: spin, promela

I wrote a model in Spin. I want to check some LTL on the model.
for example:

```
ltl L1 {<>[]Working}
```

in the Verification window i choose option "use claim"  and click "Run":

```
ltl L1: <> ([] (Working))
gcc -DMEMLIM=1024 -O2 -DXUSAFE -w -o pan pan.c
```

at this point I have no idea what to do next...?
I've tried to look for the answer with Google but there are no guides how to use Spin....

Comment: Why is @Matte Schwerhoff 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209457/1959808) not accepted ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Save your model including the `ltl`-block in `foo.pml`
2. `spin -a foo.pml`
3. `gcc -o foo.exe pan.c` (Windows)
4. `foo.exe -a`

Running the executable with `-a` is the key, otherwise, the LTL-property won't be checked.

Comment: Hey, there should be an option to compile it from spin itself.. but for some reason Spin does not recognize my C compiler.. even though I changed the "environment varibels".

Comment: @JuniorFasco What do you mean by "compile it from spin itself"?

Comment: @JuniorFasco there does exist now a [`-run` option](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Spin.html) to tell `spin` to call `gcc` and run the produced `pan`. Note that this option is new, nothing similar existed in the past.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'verification' window after your click 'run' there should be a verification result.  It looks like this (for example):

```
verification result:
spin -a  foo.pml
ltl ltl_0: [] (foo)
gcc -DMEMLIM=1024 -O2 -DXUSAFE -o pan pan.c
./pan -m10000  -a -c1
Pid: 21462

(Spin Version 6.2.4 -- 21 November 2012)
    + Partial Order Reduction
...

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
No errors found -- did you verify all claims?
```

Are you not seeing any of that?  Or are you seeing something but can't interpret it?